# How can you you add a span in a itemtemplate (code behind)

Tags: c#, html, gridview, itemtemplate, rowdatabound

I want to add a span with code behind to a itemTemple (inside a gridview)

```
<itemTemplate>
    // Here i want a span build up with code behind
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlinkID" runat="server">#</asp:HyperLink>
</itemTemplate>
```

Is this even posible or do i need to declare a placeholder in the aspx.

Comment: You can do it without having anything in the markup but it would be dificult to control the positioning and I think you are just making the job harder. I would add a `<asp:Literal>` to the markup and set the Text property. If you do not set Text to anything then nothing will render to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A span which you want to access on serverside is a [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is rendered as span later.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="LblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TextColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If you want to hide it under certain conditions i would use the `RowDataBound`-event. `Visible=false` on server-side means that it's not rendered at all on client-side.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
is it possible to add the label dynamicly in the rowdatabound method, instead of in the aspx?

Comment: @kishenBiekhram: you can switch visibility in `RowDataBound`. I'd declare it anyway. `Visible=false` means that it's not rendered at all on client-side.